# Call Contentclick event elsewhere

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a method inside the `CellContentClick` event handler to filter data as shown below:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (cboQuantity.Text == "1")
    {
        tempn = 4;
    }

    if (cboQuantity.Text == "2")
    {
        tempn = 5;
    }

    if (cboQuantity.Text == "3")
    {
        tempn = 6;
    }

    if (cboQuantity.Text == "4")
    {
        tempn = 7;
    }

    if (cboQuantity.Text == "5")
    {
        tempn = 8;
    }
    DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    txtN.Text = row.Cells[tempn].Value.ToString();
```

Unfortunately when I move this code it won't work in other methods because it depends on the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` and when I call them the method greys out and won't work

Is there a way I can signal this method (for example `button1.PerformClick` on a button)?

Comment: You should use a `Switch` instead of all of those `if`.

Comment: You should move that to a function and pass the index.

Comment: To add to @SLaks, you may need to do `instantation` when you use in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is dependent on an event fired by the DataGridViewCell (in other words, some parts of the method depend on `e`), you cannot move as is. If you want to use elsewhere, you need to "wrap" it in a method that accepts the same arguments, then pass those arguments to the method.